# Assigning values to blanks in a picklist

Tags: formula, picklist, bucket

I am trying to assign values to all the responses in a picklist including blanks so I can bucket in a report into responded and not responded.
My formula is below but I am getting multiple syntax errors. Help is appreciated:

```
CASE(Gender__c,
"other", "1",
"prefer not to say", "0",
"male", "1",
"female", "1",
"Non-binary/third gender","1"
"","0")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a comma between every parameter (you're missing one near the end), and you need a "default value" as the final parameter. There should be an **even** number of parameters total (field, value+result pairs, and default value).

Realistically, all you need to do is track the "1" values, the "0" would be everything else:

```
CASE(Gender__c,
"other", "1",
"male", "1",
"female", "1",
"Non-binary/third gender","1",
"0")
```

Comment: thank you for your helpful response. When I enter what you have noted, I am now getting an error that says the output is text when it expected a number. Number is selected as the field value. Wont my output be a number (not text) as Ive selected 1 or 0?

Comment: @Mindy99 If you're using a number return type, do not use quotes.